# Pre-processing before child iframe's $(document).ready function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, document-ready

My page (lets call it P1) has an iframe in which I load another html page (P2). That iframe page is to be opened only in a pseudo or a trial mode in P1.

From P1's scope, is it possible to access P2's scope and mark a boolean variable before P2's $(document).ready() function is called using the iframe's contentWindow look-up or otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you set a global var in P1 (by not including the `var` keyword before it) You should be able to access it in P2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a querystring in the `src` attribute of P1's iframe which passes the boolean that dictates how P2 behaves? Then, use some server-side script in P2 to grab the variable from the querystring and handle it accordingly before the page loads?

e.g:

P1 code:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/p2.html?mode=trial"/></iframe>
```

P2 code:

```
<?php if ($_GET['mode'] == trial)
{

    //Build trial page

} else {

    //Build normal page

} ?>
```

Comment: This is an option that would work but I am not sure if using a get would be safe esp when the code would be visible once someone clicks "view source" (access in the non-trial mode is not safe - tho I guess that can be managed differently).